# php heredoc variable in compound word

Tags: php, heredoc

I would like to create a compound word using a variable and hard coded text.
E.g. When passing User as the $model argument to below function:

```
function compileRepository($model) {
    return <<<TEMPLATE
    <?php

    namespace App\Repositories\Eloquent;

    use App\Models\Eloquent\\$model;
    use App\Interfaces\\$model as $modelInterface;

    class Eloquent$model implements $modelInterface {

    };
    TEMPLATE;
    }
```

I would like to get:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Repositories\Eloquent;

    use App\Models\Eloquent\User;
    use App\Interfaces\User as UserInterface;

    class EloquentUser implements UserInterface {

    };
```

Unfortunately this does not work because $modelInterface is interpreted as the variable modelInterface rather than the variable $model concatenated with Interface

Comment: Put curly brackets around the variable name. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Post it as an answer and I will accept it